# Crash happening while Scrolling the UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access, core-text

My app is getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m @autoreleasepool when i am scrolling the tableview with telugu script and only in iOS 9 not in iOS 10, i tried with iOS 8 too with simulator in that also it doesn't, and it is not crashing when i am having english/tamil script.

Also i am not getting any crash log in console, i tried get log using NSZombieEnbled yes, then in instrument which zombie object makes the crash, i am not getting any clue like which block/line of code making this crash, so i am posting my uitableview and the uitableviewcell code below

In CustomTableView.m

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1; 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return synopsisArray.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HomeViewCardCell";
    HomeViewCardCell *cell = (HomeViewCardCell *)[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HomeViewCardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    font = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"fontsize"];
    [cell setdata:[synopsisArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    [moveToTopBtn removeFromSuperview];
    NSString *tabedtag = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"tabedtagNub"];
    if ([tabedtag isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        int btnNum = (int)indexPath.row+1;
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btnNum inSection:0];
        if (synopsisArray.count > btnNum) {
            [self.tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        }
    }
    if ([tabedtag isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    scrolposindex = @"0";
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:scrolposindex forKey:@"scrolposindex"];
        NSString *catname = [[synopsisArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"categoryName"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"categoryButtonPressed"];
        [_delegate pushCategoryScreen:catname categoryID:[[synopsisArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"categoryID"] entryID:nil];
    }
    if ([tabedtag isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        [moveToTopBtn removeFromSuperview];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:indexPath.row forKey:@"cattapeindex"];
        SynopsisTable *synoptable=[synopsisArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_delegate pushReadWebviewScreen:synoptable.externalURL navbarTitle:synoptable.Source];
    }
    if ([tabedtag isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        AppDelegate *appdelegate =(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        [appdelegate startActivity];
        NSArray *itemsToShare;
        SynopsisTable *synoptable=[synopsisArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        itemsToShare = @[[NSURL URLWithString:synoptable.shareUrl]];
        [_delegate presentShareContentView:itemsToShare];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"tabedtagNub"];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    indexNumber = indexPath.row;
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (lastContentOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        [moveToTopBtn removeFromSuperview];
        [_delegate newArticlemsghideshow:YES];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{moveToTopBtn.alpha =    0.0;} completion:nil];
    } else if (lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{moveToTopBtn.alpha = 1.0;} completion:nil];
        [self toptomovebutncreate];
        [_delegate newArticlemsghideshow:NO];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)offset {
    if (offset->y+scrollView.frame.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height - 1) {
            NSLog(@"tableview load more happened");
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"ReloadCategoryVC"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"RequestFromTimer"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"no" forKey:@"tabedmenu"];
            SynopsisTable *synoptable = [synopsisArray lastObject];
            [_delegate tableViewLodeMore:synoptable.entryID];
    }
}
```

In HomeViewCardCell.h

```
@interface HomeViewCardCell : UITableViewCell <UIWebViewDelegate> {
NSString *BGColor;
NSString *TextColor;
SDImageCache *imageCache;
UIWebView *videoWebView;
IBOutlet UILabel *splittext;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *nextcartbtn;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *catnamebtn;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *readmorebtn;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *sharebtn;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titlelab;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoimg;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *datelab;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *boarderview;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *placeholderview;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIImageView * imageview;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *downloadButton;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *catnameNo;
@property (nonatomic,assign) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *entryidarray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *textcolor;

-(void)updateFonts;
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
-(void)setdata:(NSDictionary *)syntable;
-(IBAction)loadImageView:(NSString *)entryId;

@end
```

In HomeCardViewCell.m

```
@implementation HomeViewCardCell {
    NSString *imgStr;
    NSNumber *fontNo;
}

@synthesize imageview,downloadButton,nextcartbtn,catnamebtn,readmorebtn,sharebtn,titlelab,logoimg,datelab,boarderview,placeholderview,imageView,catnameNo;

-(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
      // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(void)setdata:(NSDictionary *)syntable {
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    [videoWebView removeFromSuperview];
    downloadButton.hidden = YES;
    BGColor = [SaveGetValue getValue:@"BGColor"];
    TextColor = [SaveGetValue getValue:@"TxtColor"];
    fontNo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"fontsize"];
    imgStr = [syntable valueForKey:@"entryImgURL"];
    NSString *datetime = [syntable valueForKey:@"entryPublishTime"];
    NSString *categoryName = [syntable valueForKey:@"categoryName"];
    if (![[syntable valueForKey:@"embedCode"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        imageview.image = nil ;
       NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@",[syntable valueForKey:@"embedCode"]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        videoWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:imageview.frame];
        [videoWebView loadRequest:request];
        [videoWebView setNeedsLayout];
        videoWebView.delegate=self;
        [videoWebView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
        videoWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = YES;
        videoWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        videoWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
        [self.contentView addSubview:videoWebView];
    } else {
        videoWebView = nil;
        imgStr = [imgStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"300x80" withString:@"748x80"];
        imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] initWithNamespace:@"ImageCacheFolder"];
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [imageCache queryCacheOperationForKey:[syntable valueForKey:@"entryID"] done:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                if (image) {
                    downloadButton.hidden = YES;
                    [imageview setImage:image];
                } else {
                    NSString *currentNetwork = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CurrentNetwork"];
                    NSArray *downloadNetworks = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DownloadNetworks"];
                    if (([[downloadNetworks objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"SwitchUp"] && [currentNetwork isEqualToString:@"Wifi"]) || ([[downloadNetworks objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"SwitchUp"] && [currentNetwork isEqualToString:@"4G"]) || ([[downloadNetworks objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"SwitchUp"] && [currentNetwork isEqualToString:@"3G"]) || ([[downloadNetworks objectAtIndex:3] isEqualToString:@"SwitchUp"] && [currentNetwork isEqualToString:@"2G"])) {
                        [self loadImageView:[syntable valueForKey:@"entryID"]];
                    }  else {
                        downloadButton.hidden = NO;
                        downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(width/2.25, width/4.2, downloadButton.frame.size.width, downloadButton.frame.size.height);
                        downloadButton.tag = [[syntable valueForKey:@"entryID"] integerValue] ;
                        [downloadButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"download_icon"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        [downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                        [imageview sd_setImageWithURL:nil placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PlaceholderImage-Day"]] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
                        [imageview addSubview:downloadButton];
                    }
                }
            }];
        });
    }
    // Title Label
    titlelab.text = [syntable valueForKey:@"entryTitle"];
    titlelab.textColor = [UIColor getUIColorFromHex:[SaveGetValue getValue:@"TxtColor"] alpha:1.0];
    titlelab.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontNo.floatValue+2];

    // Content Label
    NSString *exDesc = [[syntable valueForKey:@"extraDesc"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<li style='line-height:30px;'>" withString:@""];
    NSArray *splitArray = [exDesc componentsSeparatedByString:@"</li>"];
    splitArray = [splitArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
              [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
    NSString *appendedStr = @"";
    for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *str = [splitArray objectAtIndex:i];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<li>" withString:@""];
        NSString *bulletPoint = @"  •";
        NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ \n",bulletPoint,str];
        appendedStr = [appendedStr stringByAppendingString:formattedString];
    }
    splittext.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:fontNo.floatValue];
    splittext.textColor = [UIColor getUIColorFromHex:[SaveGetValue getValue:@"TxtColor"] alpha:1.0];
    splittext.text = appendedStr;

    // Category Button Enable/Disable
    NSInteger catagoryindex = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"catagoryIndex"] integerValue];
    if (catagoryindex == 0 || catagoryindex == 1) {
        if ([catnameNo isEqualToString:@"catnameNo"]) {
            categoryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",datetime];
            datelab.text = categoryName;
        } else {
            categoryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"     %@    ",categoryName];
            datelab.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" - %@",datetime];
            [catnamebtn setTitle:[categoryName capitalizedString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    } else {
        datelab.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",datetime];
    }
    NSString *nextcardIcon;
    NSString *ShareIcon;
    NSString *boarderline;
    NSString *logoimage;
    NSString *bgcolor;
    if ([BGColor isEqualToString:@"#404040"]) {
        ShareIcon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ShareIcon-Night"];
        nextcardIcon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NextCardIcon-Nigt"];
        logoimage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"60Sec-nightmode"];
        bgcolor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#2b2b2b"];
        //2b2b2b 3b3b3b
        boarderline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#2e2e2e"];
    } else {
        nextcardIcon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NextCardIcon-Day"];
        ShareIcon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ShareIcon-Day"];
        logoimage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"60Sec-icon-daymode"];
        bgcolor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#dedede"];
        boarderline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#cfcfcf"];
    }
    [readmorebtn setTitleColor:[UIColor getUIColorFromHex:TextColor alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    logoimg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:logoimage];
    [sharebtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:ShareIcon] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextcartbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nextcardIcon] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    placeholderview.backgroundColor = [UIColor getUIColorFromHex:BGColor alpha:1.0];
    placeholderview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    placeholderview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor getUIColorFromHex:boarderline alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    boarderview.backgroundColor = [UIColor getUIColorFromHex:boarderline alpha:1.0];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor getUIColorFromHex:bgcolor alpha:1.0];
}

-(IBAction)loadImageView:(NSString *)entryId {
    [downloadButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [imageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PlaceholderImage-Day"]] completed:^(UIImage *setImage, NSError *err, SDImageCacheType cachetype, NSURL *url) {
            if (setImage) {
                [imageCache storeImage:setImage forKey:entryId toDisk:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }];
    });
}

- (void)handleTapFrom:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([Network Check]) {
        NSLog(@"image downloading");
        UIButton *img = (UIButton *) sender;
        [img removeFromSuperview];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [imageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PlaceholderImage-Day"]] completed:^(UIImage *setImage, NSError *err, SDImageCacheType cachetype, NSURL *url) {
                if (setImage) {
                    [imageCache storeImage:setImage forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[sender tag]] toDisk:YES completion:nil];
                    NSLog(@"image downloaded");
                }
            }];
        });
    } else {
        [Network showMessage:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nnwDwnldImg"]];
    }
}

- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender  {
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[sender tag]];
    NSLog(@"tagno=%@",str);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:str forKey:@"tabedtagNub"];
    if(_delegate) {
        UITableView *parent = (UITableView *)self.superview.superview;
        //UITableView *parent = (UITableView *)[self superview];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [parent indexPathForCell:self];
        [_delegate tableView:parent didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // Make sure the contentView does a layout pass here so that its subviews have their frames set, which we
    // need to use to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth below.
    [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    // Set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the mutli-line bodyLabel based on the evaluated width of the label's frame,
    // as this will allow the text to wrap correctly, and as a result allow the label to take on the correct height.
 //   self.titlelab.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.titlelab.frame);
 //    splittext.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(splittext.frame);
}

- (void)updateFonts {
    NSNumber *font = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"fontsize"];
    self.titlelab.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:font.integerValue+2];
    splittext.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:font.integerValue];
}

@end
```

HomeCardViewCell Xib

[image: HomeCardViewCell Xib]

using autolayout for dynamic height of uitableview and uilabel.

Got a crash report from Crashlytics, adding that stack trace here

```
# OS Version: 9.3.5 (13G36)
# Device: iPod Touch 5G
# RAM Free: 13.8%
# Disk Free: 94.1%

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreText                       0x24f17664 TOpenTypeMorph::SetLookups(OTL::GSUB&, unsigned long const*, OTL::GlyphLookups&) + 131
1  CoreText                       0x24f176f3 TOpenTypeMorph::SetLookups(OTL::GSUB&, unsigned long const*, OTL::GlyphLookups&) + 274
2  CoreText                       0x24f185ad void TOpenTypeMorph::ApplyShapingEngine<TInlineVector<unsigned long, 30ul> >(OTL::GSUB&, OTL::GlyphLookups&, unsigned long*, CFRange, TInlineVector<unsigned long, 30ul>&, bool&, SyncState&) + 508
3  CoreText                       0x24f17871 TOpenTypeMorph::ShapeGlyphs(SyncState&) + 300
4  CoreText                       0x24edc077 TShapingEngine::ShapeGlyphs(TLine&, TCharStream const*) + 214
5  CoreText                       0x24edd80d TTypesetter::FinishEncoding(std::__1::tuple<TLine const*, TCharStream const*, void const* (*)(__CTRun const*, __CFString const*, void*), void*, std::__1::shared_ptr<TBidiLevelsProvider>*, unsigned int, unsigned char> const&, TLine&, signed char) + 160
6  CoreText                       0x24eae707 TTypesetterAttrString::Initialize(__CFAttributedString const*) + 406
7  CoreText                       0x24eae4e3 TTypesetterAttrString::TTypesetterAttrString(__CFAttributedString const*) + 102
8  CoreText                       0x24eae359 CTLineCreateWithAttributedString + 56
9  UIFoundation                   0x271a2b57 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 12742
10 UIFoundation                   0x2719f97d -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 132
11 UIKit                          0x2722dcab -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 794
12 UIKit                          0x2722d981 -[UILabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 56
13 UIKit                          0x2722d8a7 -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 134
14 UIKit                          0x2732ab43 -[UILabel intrinsicContentSize] + 82
15 UIKit                          0x2732a963 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 30
16 UIKit                          0x2732a3f3 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 574
17 UIKit                          0x273269c7 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 238
18 UIKit                          0x2732a1ad -[UILabel updateConstraints] + 304
19 UIKit                          0x27a659df -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 462
20 UIKit                          0x27a65c59 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 168
21 UIKit                          0x27a658f5 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 228
22 Foundation                     0x2343ddf9 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 256
23 UIKit                          0x2732937d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 52
24 UIKit                          0x27a65c35 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 132
25 Foundation                     0x2343ddf9 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 256
26 UIKit                          0x2732937d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 52
27 UIKit                          0x27329ecb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 582
28 UIKit                          0x278415e7 -[UITableViewCellContentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 182
29 UIKit                          0x27a63733 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:hasIntentionallyCollapsedHeight:] + 382
30 UIKit                          0x276a8edf -[UITableViewCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:] + 438
31 UIKit                          0x2756ce5b -[UITableView _heightForCell:atIndexPath:] + 442
32 UIKit                          0x2736e743 __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 3186
33 UIKit                          0x27231541 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 72
34 UIKit                          0x2736dac3 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 458
35 UIKit                          0x275694cd -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 776
36 UIKit                          0x275695a5 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 68
37 UIKit                          0x27558b51 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2272
38 UIKit                          0x2756dd1b -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 78
39 UIKit                          0x2730d23b -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 178
40 UIKit                          0x2721ea73 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 714
41 QuartzCore                     0x252b6bcd -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 128
42 QuartzCore                     0x252b2375 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 348
43 QuartzCore                     0x252b2209 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
44 QuartzCore                     0x252b16d1 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 368
45 QuartzCore                     0x252b13a5 CA::Transaction::commit() + 520
46 QuartzCore                     0x253038ff CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 762
47 IOMobileFramebuffer            0x249ea50b IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 86
48 IOKit                          0x22ef8759 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
49 CoreFoundation                 0x22c5637d __CFMachPortPerform + 132
50 CoreFoundation                 0x22c6a5b3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
51 CoreFoundation                 0x22c69cc7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
52 CoreFoundation                 0x22c680d9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1688
53 CoreFoundation                 0x22bb7229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
54 CoreFoundation                 0x22bb7015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
55 GraphicsServices               0x241a7ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
56 UIKit                          0x2728b189 UIApplicationMain + 144
57 60SecondsNow                   0x127799 main (main.m:15)
58 libdispatch.dylib              0x2285f873 (Missing)
```

by this crash report i am guessing that it may be a issue in coretext library for telugu language script, kindly help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a Bug in Bug Reporter for the above crash issue especially for Telugu Script.

Got a Reply from Apple Like below

""
Apple Developer Relations

Engineering has provided the following information regarding this issue:

This is crashing in CoreText. However, if this is resolved in iOS 10, we are not able to make an update to iOS 9. Please verify and ensure its working on iOS 11.

iOS 11 beta 7 (15A5362a)
https://developer.apple.com/download/

If the issue persists, please attach a new sysdiagnose captured in the latest build and attach it to the bug report.

iOS sysdiagnose Instructions:
https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/iOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf

---

For a complete list of logging instructions visit:
https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/  ""